# setcookie function is not working

Tags: php

> I am using these below code in a.php

```
$cookieId = rand(100000,999999);
setcookie('senderSession', $cookieId); 
echo $_COOKIE['senderSession'];
```

> I am using these below code in b.php

```
$cookieId = rand(100000,999999);
setcookie('travelerSession', $cookieId); 
echo $_COOKIE['travelerSession'];
```

**But both are giving blank. Both files are using in a project.**

Comment: the set cookie will only be available to read in the _next_ page load!

Comment: From the docs: _Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE array._

Comment: I am access it on another page but getting blank.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what question is, but I have an idea.

**PHP Create/Retrieve a Cookie**
The following example creates a cookie named "user" with the value "A.Kushwaha". The cookie will expire after 30 days (86400 * 30). The "/" means that the cookie is available in entire website (otherwise, select the directory you prefer).

We then retrieve the value of the cookie "user" (using the global variable $_COOKIE). We also use the isset() function to find out if the cookie is set:

```
  <?php
   $cookie_name = "user";
   $cookie_value = "A.Kushwaha";
   setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");// 86400 = 1 day
   ?>
   <html>
   <body>

   <?php
   if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
   echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
   } else {
   echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
   echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: I am getting from your code Cookie named 'user' is not set!

Comment: Sorry after again refresh I am getting.